# Unable to load images using SDL_LoadBMP

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I have very limited experience with SDL1.2 and I am also trying to migrate to SDL2.0.
This is a simple Tic Tac Toe game and the following Class loads my images upon initialization. I am unable to pinpoint exactly my problem, but I got an Exit with Code -1 because it fails to load my bitmaps. My desired result is to return TRUE.
Code is initially from http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-tutorial-tic-tac-toe but i made some changes for migrating over to SDL2.0.

```
bool CApp::OnInit() {

if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) { return false; }

SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(600, 600, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE, &sdlWindow, &sdlRenderer);

if((Surf_Grid = CSurface::OnLoad("./gfx/grid.bmp")) == NULL) { return false; }
if((Surf_O = CSurface::OnLoad("./gfx/o.bmp")) == NULL) { return false; }
if((Surf_X = CSurface::OnLoad("./gfx/x.bmp")) == NULL) { return false; }

Reset();

return true;}
```

I thought the problem lies in CSurface::Onload(), so I insert a breakpoint in the function but project runs out without reaching my breakpoint. It seems that the CSurface::Onload() function doesn't seem to be invoked.

CSurface::Onload():

```
SDL_Surface* CSurface::OnLoad(char* File) {
SDL_Surface* Surf_Temp = NULL;
SDL_Surface* Surf_Return = NULL;

if((Surf_Temp = SDL_LoadBMP(File)) == NULL) { return NULL; }

Surf_Return = SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat(Surf_Temp,SDL_PIXELFORMAT_UNKNOWN,0);    /* OUTDATED SDL 1.2 : Surf_Return = SDL_DisplayFormat(Surf_Temp); */
SDL_FreeSurface(Surf_Temp);
return Surf_Return;}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here???

Answer (score 1):

Took some time, but finally discovered that the issue lies with the pixel format field for the function SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat()
i have close to no idea what these fields mean but the issue is resolved simply by using SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888

http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat

resolved. =)

Comment: Basically this is what should be expected. SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat is used to change the pixel format to a different type. SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB888 is generally the more common as it represents 8-bit per pixel see here - https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PixelFormat What you were saying by using SDL_PIXELFORMAT_UNKNOWN is "I want to change my pixel format to another one but I don't know what that is"

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling in a Windows environment, did you try to use backslashes instead of forward-slashes in your path notation for your `CSurface::OnLoad()` method invocations?

Comment: i tried both forward and backward slashes. and double backwards slashes. doesn't appear to be the problem.